# Why can two implicit conversions exist that differ only by return constness?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, implicit-conversion

Consider the following code:

```
#include <string>

class WrapperString
{
public:
    WrapperString(const std::string& str) : str_(str) {}

    operator std::string() const { return str_; }
    operator const std::string() const { return str_; }

    std::string get() const { return str_; }
    // error C2373: 'WrapperString::get' : redefinition; different type modifiers
    // const std::string get() const { return str_; }

private:
    std::string str_;
};

int main (int, char *[])
{
    WrapperString w( "Hello" );
    std::string foo = w; // disabling either implicit conversion makes this work
    return 0;
}
```

Why does `WrapperString` actually compile given the two implicit conversions differ only by their `const`ness?  One cannot achieve this result by declaring a named method.

BTW, this is VS2010.

**EDIT** :  Just to be clear, I added the `get()` methods as a logical counterexample as to why it doesn't make sense to have two implicit conversions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does WrapperString actually compile given the two implicit conversions differ only by their constness

The return type is not the only difference: `operator std::string` and `operator const std::string` are **names** of these two functions, and they happen to be different in this case, unlike the names of the `get` member functions.

`$3[basic]/4:` "A name is a use of [...] conversion-function-id"

`$12.3.2.1[class.conv.fct]/1:`

```
conversion-function-id:
    operator conversion-type-id
```

If you'd like, you could call them by those names using plain function call syntax.

```
 std::string s1 = w.operator std::string();
 std::string s2 = w.operator const std::string();
 std::string s3 = w.get(); // which get?
```

Comment: Different names for different conversion functions are more of an implementation detail than a rationale.

Comment: @BenVoigt perhaps -- the same semantics could have been specified in different terms (e.g. by making a special exception for conversion functions when specifying what can and can't be overloaded) -- but that's how it's specified now (to the best of my understanding).

Answer (score 4):

These are conversions to two different types, one of which is const, one not.  Constness is part of the type.

This is different than the proscription against functions with identical signatures that return different types.